# connecting event in pyside qtableview

Tags: python, selection, pyside, signals-slots, qtableview

I need a simple example: how to connect *selectRow event* (if exist this event in pyside) and call respective handler. For example

```
self.table_view.selectedRow.connect(lambda: self.handler(param))
```

Comment: Could you post a working code for suggestions? I mean a minimal example of your `TableView` with some data and what you want to do.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using a QTableView, you need to connect to the [selectionChanged](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectionChanged) signal of its [selectionModel](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel). You can then use the [selectedRows](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectedRows) method of the selection model to get the selected row(s) (where "selected row" means the *whole row* is selected).

Here's a simple demo:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, rows, columns):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.table = QtGui.QTableView(self)
        model =  QtGui.QStandardItemModel(rows, columns, self.table)
        for row in range(rows):
            for column in range(columns):
                item = QtGui.QStandardItem('(%d, %d)' % (row, column))
                item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
                model.setItem(row, column, item)
        self.table.setModel(model)
        selection = self.table.selectionModel()
        selection.selectionChanged.connect(self.handleSelectionChanged)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)

    def handleSelectionChanged(self, selected, deselected):
        for index in self.table.selectionModel().selectedRows():
            print('Row %d is selected' % index.row())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window(5, 5)
    window.show()
    window.setGeometry(600, 300, 600, 250)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you #ekhumoro for answering and it is really helpful. 
I also tried modify your code

```
#from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore                                         #           

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, rows, columns):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.table = QtGui.QTableView(self)
        self.table.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QTableView.SingleSelection)   #
        self.table.setSelectionBehavior(QtGui.QTableView.SelectRows)    #
        model =  QtGui.QStandardItemModel(rows, columns, self.table)
        for row in range(rows):
            for column in range(columns):
                item = QtGui.QStandardItem('(%d, %d)' % (row, column))
                item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
                model.setItem(row, column, item)
        self.table.setModel(model)
    #    selection = self.table.selectionModel()
    #    selection.selectionChanged.connect(self.handleSelectionChanged)
        self.table.selectionModel().currentRowChanged.connect(self.handleSelectionChanged)
        self.assetChanged(self.table.currentIndex())
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)

    #def handleSelectionChanged(self, selected, deselected):
    #    for index in self.table.selectionModel().selectedRows():
    #        print('Row %d is selected' % index.row())
    def handleSelectionChanged(self, index):                                      #
        if index.isValid():                                             #
            print('Row %d is selected' % index.row())                   #

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window(5, 5)
    window.show()
    window.setGeometry(600, 300, 600, 250)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```